# Reading a permissioned denied folder returns TRUE

Tags: java, java-io

I am making a folder READ-ONLY. I am trying to check whether it is read-only.

```
File file1 = new File("path");
Sysout(file1.canRead());
```

The above code gives me TRUE but it should be FALSE. I am running this within main() method in java.

I am using JDK 1.7.0_67 version.

Can any one comment on this. Thanks.

Comment: Use these for file permission change                            **1. file.setExecutable(boolean); – true, allow execute operations; false to disallow it.
2. file.setReadable(boolean); – true, allow read operations; false to disallow it.
3. file.setWritable(boolean); – true, allow write operations; false to disallow it.**

Comment: A READ-ONLY folder can not be written to, but it can be read - as the name says.

Comment: To put what @ThomasStets said another way: read-only means that `canWrite()` would return false, but since the "only" thing you can do on a read-only file is **read** then of course `canRead()` returns true.

Comment: canRead() and canWrite() both returns TRUE in my case where I expect canRead to be FALSE. Just adding a note that Files.isReadable(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("path")) gives me FALSE for the same path. I wonder why is the difference.

Comment: JFYI that I am denying the folder permission by right clicking on the folder name, going to security tab and tick box against READ option in DENY column for my user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are testing this in Windows. In Windows, if you mark a folder as read-only, the read-only attribute applies only to the files inside that folder.

Therefore, if you check `File.canRead()` on the folder path, it will still return `true`, but if you try to check `File.canRead()` on a file inside the read-only folder, it should give you false.

Comment: Yes Dev-an. I am using Windows. You mean File.canRead() only for files and not for folders or sub-folders. If that is the case, then how to identify at folder level in windows.

Comment: @Dev-an I think you are missing something here. read-only only affects your ability to *write*. It does *not* mean you can't read, it means you can *only* read.

Comment: @Thomas Stets - Just adding to the scenario. I have made a folder DENY READ. So, file.canRead() should be FALSE but it return TRUE.